# Удаление группы при удалении ее елементов SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть три таблицы: `data` (контент страницы), `section` (секции для группировки), `hub` (сгруппированный контент).

---

`hub`

| page | data | section |
| --- | --- | --- |
| index | 1 | *NULL* |
| about | 2 | 1 |
| about | 3 | 1 |
| about | 4 | *NULL* |
| contacts | 5 | 2 |
| contacts | NULL | 1 |

> `contacts / NULL / 1` *на интерфейсе включит в себя: `data 2,3`*

---

`section`

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo |
| 2 | bar |
| 3 | baz |

> `3 / baz` *еще не использовалась (ее не надо удалять)*

---

`data`

| id | content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | some text - 1 |
| 2 | some text - 2 |
| 3 | some text - 3 |
| 4 | some text - 4 |
| 5 | some text - 5 |

---

Поступает запрос на удаление двух блоков контента **2**, **5**, удаляю `DELETE FROM data WHERE id IN(2,5)`, при удалении `data=5`, секция **2** тоже должна быть удалена.
Замысел такой:

> получить `id` секций у блоков **2**, и **5** `>>>` посчитать сколько всего элементов у секции `>>>` посчитать количество элементов секции которые будут удалены `>>>` если количество элементов у секции удаляемых и общее количество совпадает удалить секцию `>>>` удалить блоки из `hub`

Вот что получилось:

```sql
DELETE FROM `section` 
WHERE `id` IN(
    SELECT `hub`.`section` 
    FROM (
      # всего элементов у секции
        SELECT `to`.`section`, COUNT(`to`.`section`) AS `count`
        FROM `hub` AS `to` INNER JOIN (
            SELECT `section`, COUNT(`section`) AS `count`
            FROM `hub`
            WHERE `data` IN(4,5) AND `section` IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY `section`) AS `from`
        ON `to`.`section` = `from`.`section`
        GROUP BY `to`.`section`) AS `hub` 
        INNER JOIN ( 
          # количество элементов секции которые будут удалены
            SELECT `section`, COUNT(`section`) AS `count`
            FROM `hub`
            WHERE `data` IN(4,5) AND `section` IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY `section`) AS `del` USING(`section`)
    WHERE `del`.`count` = `hub`.`count`)
```

Смущает размер запроса и дублированный `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT `section`, COUNT(`section`) AS `count`
FROM `hub`
WHERE `data` IN(4,5) AND `section` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `section`) AS `del` USING(`section`)
```

Думал создать временную таблицу, но к ней можно можно подключиться раз.

Можно ли сделать как то лаконичнее? И верна ли реализация логики удаления?

---

```sql
CREATE TABLE `data` (
    `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `content` text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `hub` (
`page` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`section` int(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`data` int(11) UNSIGNED NULL,
    UNIQUE (`page`, `section`, `data`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `page-I`(`page`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `section-I`(`section`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `data-I`(`data`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `page-FK` FOREIGN KEY (`data`)
        REFERENCES `data` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT               
) ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `section` (
    `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- исходные данные

INSERT INTO section VALUES
(1, 'foo'),
(2, 'bar'),
(3, 'baz');

INSERT INTO data VALUES
(1, 'some text - 1'),
(2, 'some text - 2'),
(3, 'some text - 3'),
(4, 'some text - 4'),
(5, 'some text - 5');

INSERT INTO hub (`page`, `data`, `section`) VALUES
('index',   1,  NULL),
('about',   2,  1),
('about',   3,  1),
('about',   4,  NULL),
('contacts',    5,  2),
('contacts',    NULL,   1);
```

Comment: Покажите пример данных в виде CREATE TABLE (полностью! включая внешние ключи) + INSERT INTO. А также конечное состояние данных в виде форматированных таблиц для именно показанных данных, без всяких там многоточий. PS. content/comment для задачи не нужны.

Comment: @Akina Поправил

Comment: а триггер не?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если я верно понял связи, то

```sql
DELETE data, hub, section
FROM data
LEFT JOIN hub ON data.id = hub.data
LEFT JOIN section ON section.id = hub.section
WHERE data.id IN(2,5)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=68d0e16fd3baf885eecf746888dcf045

Чтобы не пытаться прибить лишнее и получить ошибку, надо создать внешний ключ hub-section и добавить в запрос на удаление `IGNORE`.

---

**UPDATE**

В соответствии с исправлениями исходных данных и демонстрацией требуемого результата:

1. Создаём внешний ключ hub -> section

```sql
ALTER TABLE hub 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (section) REFERENCES section (id);
```

2. Добавляем в запрос на удаление слово IGNORE.

```sql
DELETE IGNORE data, hub, section
FROM data
LEFT JOIN hub ON data.id = hub.data
LEFT JOIN section ON section.id = hub.section
WHERE data.id IN(2,5)
```

И получаем то, что требуется: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ba43e1b024ddb4ad4c271586f0c4c555

Comment: Со связями все так, но результат должен быть [такой](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1912227fe8f8a22dec75caaa4050ae57)

Comment: @JarryRoxwell Вот ни хрена не так! Вы изменили порядок присвоения полей (источник несоответствия - то, что у Вас пример данных и структура таблицы различаются порядком полей). Ок, ща... добавлено.

Comment: Извиняюсь мой косяк,  к дампу не добавил данные вставки, вопрос дополнил